# Why we call a simple java class a bean class when it is used to hold the business logic in jsp file

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I want to know why we call the bean class a "bean class"? bean class looks like a simple java class which holds the business logic in jsp file but yet we call it a bean class.

Comment: "Bean" is used in a number of contexts, so the term is a bit fuzzy, but "simple java class that encapsulates some logic" seems a good fit. What did you not like about it?

Comment: I didn't say that i don't like its naming. I just want to know that why is it named a bean class?

Comment: bean class is a special java class which must have a default public constructor with no args, all data members in bean class must be private and it is specially used to set and get the private property of bean class.

Comment: It also have the property change support feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly the java class and the Bean class are similar one.

In Bean class we have getter and setter methods.

Its just a naming convention.

we call it as a bean class because Java Beans follow the Bean conventions like

1.Serializable

2.Default, no-arg constructor,

1. getX()/setX() or isX()/setX() naming convention for read/write access to private data member X.

4.Can use java.bean.PropertyChangeEvent to notify interested parties when values change

5.Can use java.bean.PropertyChangeListener to register for notification when a particular property changes

Answer (score 0):

The term "bean" itself is another coffee-related pun (Java is the name of a coffee flavour).

Comment: Is bean class  a pun in java?

Answer (score 0):

why we use Java beans in java, because the configuration setting of bean can be saved in persistent storage and restored at a later time.